# Softkeyboard hides elements of my layout that I want to be visibles

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I've got a layout that looks like first image and when I open the softkeyboard looks like the second image, but I want it how it seems on third image:

[image: My Layout]
[image: How it looks with keyboard opened]
[image: Result wanted]

I read a lot about adjustpan and adjustresize on the manifest but nothing works, the xml structure is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blanco"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<!-- LOGO -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.7"
    android:background="@color/green_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="65dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_registro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_registro" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6.3" >

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

First part is the green part with the app logo and inside the FrameLayout I put Fragments that contains simple LinearLayouts or RelativeLayouts with parts of my Login forms.

Comment: Have you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265

Comment: Did you find solution for this one?

Comment: Nope :( I left the issue hanging

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your Manifest, inside the activity

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: Don't work, sorry :( I don't wanna hide the keyboard by default, I want the screen scrolls to my wanted position when the keyboard opens, and not adjust automatically to the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Set your windowSoftInputMode in your manifest for this activity to be adjustResize.  THere are 3 possible settings for this-  nothing, resize (shrinks your app to fit the remaining space), and pan (scrolls your app so the focused field remains on screen).

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the empty scrollview and it will work

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>
```